# Taking AWS EBS snapshot while website on AWS is running.. OK?

Tags: amazon-aws, amazon-ec2

we have a website that's getting about 10k users everyday running on AWS instance/ebs (centos).

Now for test purposes I want to setup another replica webserver.

My question is, can I start a EBS snapshot process while the website is running? Would it work?

Also other question is that if I start the snapshot process, (it might take a few hours to complete) can I close my web browser while the snapshot process is running and login again to check status of snapshot?

Your expert assistance is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can start an EBS snapshot while the website is running.
Yes, you can close your browser.

That being said, you should realize that while your website is running there might be some data in RAM that's not yet committed to the disk. So the recommended way is to lock the tables, flush all the DB transactions to disk, freeze filesystem (like `fsfreeze` in linux), start the snapshot, then unfreeze the filesystem and resume DB operations. That should give you more or less consistent snapshot.

Comment: Thanks how long snapshot will take to replicate 1 terabyte ebs drive 10% full? Thanks